# Find the primitive root of n closest to n/φ faster than O(n)

Tags: haskell, rust, time-complexity, number-theory

I have a number *n* from 2 to around 1e9 and I need to find the primitive root of *n* that's closest to *n*/φ. For instance, if *n*=89, the primitive root I want is 56. 54 is also a primitive root, but 89/φ is just greater than 55.

If *n* has no primitive roots, I want a number of the greatest multiplicative order.

Is it possible to compute this faster than O(*n*) on average? If some freak of a number has no primitive roots near *n*/φ, it's OK to take longer for that number.

I'm writing the program in Rust and Haskell, but C++ is fine as I've also been coding in that, or pseudocode.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for/get better answers on [cs.se].

Comment: Is φ the golden ratio or Euler's totient function? Could you share the context of this problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The simplest possible approach (taking candidates starting at n/φ and checking whether they are primitive roots) should already be faster than O(n) on average. The most expensive part is probably computing the prime factorisation of n.

Comment: φ is the golden ratio; 55 and 89 are Fibonacci numbers. This is for a whole-message cipher I'm designing; *n* is 1/3 the size of the message, and the primitive root will be used to mix up the bytes.

Comment: Encrypting a message of size n will be O(n) anyway, and the simple approach outlined above is already faster than O(n), so I don't think there's value in optimizing this further (nor do I think there is much room for optimization anyway, except in computing the integer factorization of n).

Comment: Most of what you need is explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n, particularly the conditions on n for a primitive root to even exist.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk-Strike The OP asked for "a number of the greatest multiplicative order" modulo n, so conditions for primitive roots to exist are not sufficient. You need to know the structure of the [structure of the multiplicative groupd module n in the general case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#General_composite_numbers), so you can compute the least common multiple of all factor group exponents. For odd prime power factors p^k of n, the exponent is p^k–p^{k-1}, but you need to special-case powers of two.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I see that now, thanks. The "greatest multiplicative" order of n is always the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of n which has the properties you describe (lcm of the individual exponents, special case for powers of two).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk-Strike Right, it's called Carmichael function. I had forgotten that name, but I remember now. It's been many years since I learned about basic number theory. :)

Comment: Encrypting takes O(n log n) because the number of rounds increases with the message size. I imported Math.NumberTheory.ArithmeticFunctions, Data.Mod, and Math.NumberTheory.Primes and am partway through getting the Haskell code working.

Answer (score 1):

A simple an efficient algorithm to find the element of maximum order in the group of units modulo *m* closest to *m*/*φ* is this:

1. Determine the maximum order in the group of units modulo *m*, given by the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) *λ*(*m*). This requires computing the prime factorization of *m*.
2. Compute the prime factorization of *λ*(*m*).
3. Construct the sequence of numbers closest to *m*/*φ*. Start with *m*/*φ* rounded to the next integer, then take the next closest number and so on.
4. Test whether any of the numbers has order *λ*(*m*). The first one that has is the number we are looking for.

   By definition of the Carmichael function, we know that *a*^*λ*(*m*) = 1 for all *λ*. If *a* does not have maximum order, we must have *a*^(*λ*(*m*)/*p*) = 1 for some prime *p* dividing *λ*(*m*). If *a*^(*λ*(*m*)/*p*) ≠ 1 for all *p*|*λ*(*m*), *a* must have maximum order.

This check is relatively cheap. On average, we only need to check a handful of numbers before finding one of maximum order, even for moduli in the order of magnitude of 1e9. I benchmarked a [mildly optimized Rust implementation](https://github.com/smarnach/max-order-elements/blob/main/src/main.rs) of this algorithm on my machine. For odd moduli *m*, the code spends 60% of its time on the prime factorizations of *m* and *λ*(*m*), for even moduli about 40% of its time. For odd moduli it takes on average 4µs for each number, and that time hardly increases as *m* grows.